# Find and display latest version number of Github repo on external site?

Tags: github, version

I was hoping that I could display a nice download button on my WordPress site to a GitHub repository and include the version number in the text, eg: "Download (v1.2)" but am unsure as to where I can pull that version data from on the public side.

If nothing else, last commit date or something would be helpful too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the published [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/) to access commit information. For example, you can [get a commit object](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/) and use that to populate your download link. If a commit is not appropriate, you could get a tag or a blob and extract the information you want out of that.